# How to use condition in ng-required

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a field reuired field on the basis of value of another field. Value of both the fields is present in $scope as FieldA AND FieldB.

```
<input type="email" id = "abc" class="form-control" ng-required ="FielddA != FieldB" />
```

But its not working. How can I use the ng-required functionality to make field required conditionally.

Comment: I think it should work. Can you Paste your Controller code as well. Maybe there's some error which prevent it to work properly.

Comment: It did not work. Sorry I am not able to copy my code here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ng-required` with `angular.equals` like this:

First, declare function to compare values as `angular.equals` cannot be called directly from the form:

```
$scope.areEqual = function(field1, field2) {
  return angular.equals(field1, field2);
}
```

Then call it on `ng-required` like this:

```
ng-required="!areEqual(FieldA, FieldB)"
```

Here's Plunker:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/DNGaooegZx6mwX5VuU9k?p=preview

---

Source:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/function/angular.equals